# How to prevent a div from moving up when zooming in

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

So for starters this question may seem kind of vague, so I am going to do the best I can to describe my situation.

I have created a html page with adjustable sections (top left, top right, and bottom). There are dividers to adjust the X axis (between the top two sections) and to adjust the Y axis (between the top and bottom section). Everything appears to be working fine, however when I zoom in (using  command + on the keyboard), it pushes the text within the bottom section above the Y axis adjuster.

I want instead for the text to be contained in the div beneath the Y axis adjuster and never slide on top of it (even when the screen is resized or zoomed in on).

[image: before i zoom in]

The above image is what it looks like before zooming in. Notice how the text 'Element 3' is below the green line (Y axis adjuster).

[image: this is after i zoom in]

The above image is what it looks like after zooming in. Notice how the text 'Element 3' raises above the green line (Y axis adjuster).

The error should be in the HTML code, not the JS, however I included the JS files for good measure.

I looked all over the internet for a solution but came up empty handed. I have tried simply bootstrapping the page by including the appropriate script tags but that did not work, as well as adjusting various css styles.

html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>resizer</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Common.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resizer.js"></script>

    <style>
        .element{
            border: 1px solid #999999;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    margin: 5px;
                    padding: 5px;
            }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onresize() {
            var element1 = document.getElementById("element1");
            var element2 = document.getElementById("element2");
            var element3 = document.getElementById("element3");
            var ResizerY = document.getElementById("resizerY");
            ResizerY.style.top = element3.offsetTop - 15 + "px";
            var topElements = document.getElementById("topElements");
            topElements.style.height = ResizerY.offsetTop - 20 + "px";
            var height = topElements.clientHeight - 32;
            if (height < 0)
                height = 0;
            height += 'px';
            element1.style.height = height;
            element2.style.height = height;
        }
        function resizeX(x) {
            var element2 = document.getElementById("element2");
            element2.style.width =
                element2.parentElement.clientWidth
                + document.getElementById('rezizeArea').offsetLeft
                - x
                + 'px';
        }
        function resizeY(y) {
            var element3 = document.getElementById("element3");
            var height =
                element3.parentElement.clientHeight
                + document.getElementById('rezizeArea').offsetTop
                - y
            ;

            if ((height + 100) > element3.parentElement.clientHeight)
                return;//Limit of the height of the elemtnt 3
            element3.style.height = height + 'px';
            onresize();
        }
        var emailSubject = "Resizer example error";
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="rezizeArea" style="top=0; bottom=0; right=0; left=0; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; position: absolute;" class="element">
        <div id="topElements" class="element" style="overflow:auto; position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right:0;">
            <div id="element2" class="element" style="width: 30%; height:10px; float: right; position: relative;">
                Element 2
            </div>
            <div id="resizerX" style="width: 10px; height:100%; background: red; float: right;"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                resizerX("resizerX", function (e) {
                    resizeX(e.pageX + 25);
                });
            </script>
            <div id="element1" class="element" style="height:10px; overflow:auto;">
                Element 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="resizerY" style="height:10px; position:absolute; left: 0; right:0; background: green;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            resizerY("resizerY", function (e) {
                resizeY(e.pageY + 25);
            });
        </script>
        <div id="element3" class="element" style="display: inline-block; height:100px; position:absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; right:0;">
            Element 3
        </div> 
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        onresize();
    </script>
    <hr>

</body>
</html>
```

resizer.js:

```
function resizer(resizerID, mousemove, cursor) {
    consoleLog("resizer(" + resizerID + ")");
    var resizer = document.getElementById(resizerID);
    resizer.style.cursor = cursor;
    resizer.mousemove = mousemove;

    resizer.onmousedown = function (e) {
        try{
            consoleLog("resizer.onmousedown(e)");
            document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', resizer.doDrag, false);
            document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', resizer.stopDrag, false);
        } catch (e) {
            ErrorMessage("resizer.onmousedown(...) failed! Your browser does not support this feature. " + e.message);
        }
    }

    resizer.doDrag = function (e) {
        if (e.which != 1){
            consoleLog("mouseup");
            resizer.stopDrag(e);
            return;
        }
        //consoleLog("doDrag(e)");
        resizer.mousemove(e);
    }

    resizer.stopDrag = function (e) {
        consoleLog("stopDrag(e)");
        document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', resizer.doDrag, false);
        document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', resizer.stopDrag, false);
    }
}

function resizerX(resizerID, mousemove) {
    resizer(resizerID, mousemove, "e-resize");
}

function resizerY(resizerID, mousemove) {
    resizer(resizerID, mousemove, "n-resize");
}
```

Common.js:

```
function MessageElement(Message) {
    var element = document.getElementById('Message');
    if (element == null) {
        alert('ERROR: element Message == null. ' + Message);
        return;
    }
    if (element.innerHTML != Message)
    {
        //consoleLog('Message: ' + Message);
        element.innerHTML = Message + '<hr><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="javascript: return MessageElement(\'\')" value="Close" style="margin-top:5px;" /></div>';
        if (Message == "")
            element.style.display = "none";
        else element.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function ErrorMessage(message, emailMe) {
    consoleError(message);

    //http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html
    var body;
    if (emailMe != false) {
        body = message;
        body = body.replace(/\n/g, "%0D%0A");
        body = body.replace(/ /g, "%20");
        body = body.replace(/"/g, "%22");
        body = body.replace(/&/g, "%26");
    }
    message = message.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
    message = message.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');

    message = message.replace(/\n/g, '<BR>');
    if (emailMe != false) {
        //http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/mailto.htm
        if (typeof myEmail == 'undefined')
            myEmail = "XXX";
        message += "<BR><BR><a href=\"mailto:" + myEmail + "?subject=" + emailSubject + "&body=" + body + "\" >Email me about problem</a>"
    }
    MessageElement('<FONT style="color: red; background-color: white">ERROR: ' + message + '</FONT>');
}

function consoleLog(message) {
    try{
        console.log(message);//Do not works in WP
    } catch(e) {
    }
}

function consoleError(msg)
{
    try
    {
        console.error(msg);
    } catch(e) {
//      alert(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that `position:absolute` is the problem

Comment: I tried removing position:absolute or replacing it with another position option and it completely rearranges the page, so i do not believe that is the cause.  I think it may somehow need to be contained within another div or container to anchor it in place but wrapping the Y axis selector takes away its functionality to resize the page. I would think it would be something along those lines though.

Comment: hey, let me clarify the problem..
here when you zoom in the browser desktop size will be reduce and you sets height of elements 1 & 2 by JavaScript(resizer.js).
when you zoom it will only change your browser size not reload your page. so after zoom you just need to reload the page because you set height from JavaScript.
So your code id alright, there is no bugs you need to reload page after zooming.